# User Manager with Download access documents with documents groups role assign

Tags: wordpress

I would like to integrate below functionality to WordPress any help would be appreciate.

- Show list of documents and filter document as per categories
- User management (login, registration and forgot password)
- Without login if user try to download document then it will show popup and ask for registration
- With login only show document which user can access or assign by admin
- Admin can upload document with categories selection and assign to group for user.
- Admin will give access to user with group assign

Is there any ready made plugin available like this functionality, or is it possible with few different plugins?